# Which datatype and which insertion parameter for large data

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-ce, dataadapter

Here a field in my data records could pass the limit of 8000 chars of nvarchar, and looking for a quite larger Data-Type, e.g about 9000 chars,  Any ideas ?
At first I was using `NvarChar(8000)`, after finding some could pass this boundary I used `NText`
to see what will happen next, with Entity Framework seems it could do the job as it's expected without defining any `Insert statement` and `Data Adapter`, During the programming the system changed to data Adapter and I should do the job with a Insert command, Now the parameter defined is look like this :

```
cmdIns.Parameters.Add("@story", SqlDbType.NText, 16, "Story")
```

it seems that the limitation of **16** will be increased automatically while using `EF` is used but not with the `Data Adapter`(*And it just insert 16 chars of the data*),
really don't know (can't remember) Is the test with EF passed even the items larger than **8000** ?
If so, I'm curious about the reason.

The situation is deciding the **proper Data-Type and it's equivalent working parameter** to be used on insertion point of this large data field.

**Note :** Here SQL Server CE is Used

---

**Edit :**

Sorry, I had to go at that time,
The Data-type which should be used is `NTEXT` with no alternative here
but defining the `**insertion Statement and parameter**` is a bit hassle,
unfortunately none of the suggested methods could do the desired job similar to the piece which I gave.

- without defining the length it will give errors (run-time) !
- And Using **AddWithValue** couldn't use a the DataAdapter and do the insertion in bulk.
  Maybe I have to place it in another question, but this is a piece of this question, and a working answer here could be the complete one.
  Any ideas ?

Comment: Can't you avoid stating the size? I think there is an overload just accepting the name, type and value.

Comment: Seems it should be right, I wanted to test this way, but forgot to test that way, but I think I should make a new parameter instance and within it's constructor pass the 2 parameter and omit saying the size.

Comment: That was my thought, I'm trying on it, anyway if you are sure about the method given, please post and give the definition I'll mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly you should be fine doing something like this, omitting the size as it isn't necessary:

```
cmdIns.Parameters.Add( new SqlParameter( "story", SqlDbType.NText )
{
    Value = yourVariable;
} );
```

Comment: +1, first participant of this question, thanks, seems 2 other answers are closer to the best-practices than this idea, will try all before the last response.

Comment: It will give Errors in run-time

Comment: What kind of errors? I've just checked and I use code as shown above all the time. What type is cmdIns (I assume SqlCommand)?

Comment: It was said the value can't be empty, maybe again that's another fault of SQL CE !

Comment: Thanks involved here, will make a new question with more specific details on the new pieces of the issue,

Comment: Now where you mention SQL CE I remember that you have to treat null values differently compared to SQL Server. If I remember correctly, you will have to explicitly assign `DBNull.Value` in case any of your parameters is null.

Answer (score 1):

Use AddWithValue whenever you want to add a parameter by specifying its name and value. Like this command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@story", story);

Comment: This was my prefered method for long time in similar cases but here it won't work